# FOR XML EXPLICIT - Generating &#163;

Tags: sql-server, xml, escaping, for-xml

I have an issue when using FOR XML EXPLICIT.

Basically we (our company) use a document printing company that we send XML to. I am in the process of developing a new document and one of the sentences needed is:

"Pays £98 each month for up to 12 months in any claim."

The printing company cant process the £ sign so have asked for it to be in the format of &#163; which I though was easy to achieve. So I have built the string in SQL but when the output is generated, FOR XML EXPLICIT generates &amp;#163; which the company doesn't want either.

Please can you help me output the literal string &#163;

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you processing the returned values from SQL? What do you do with them before they go to the printing company?

Comment: Hi. The xml is zipped and sent via ftp. I could change the appliation that does this but I am trying to avoid this at all costs. The application has been running for months and I dont want to disturb it. Thanks

Comment: How is the string stored in SQL? As `£` or as `&#163;`? How are you saving the XML to disk before zipping? How are you retrieving it, in code, from SQL Server?

Comment: The sql string is built up in a SP and is currently written as &#163; The application reads the xml using an xmlreader in c# but I'm not overly keen on modifying the app if i can get away with it. Ta

Comment: That's the problem then - the `XmlReader` is encoding the first `&` as `&amp;`. You will need to change the application one way or another.

Comment: I'm currently only testing the output in sql management studio by running the sp. sql ms is converting & to &amp;

Answer (score 0):

You should use the modificators (element, xml).
See this

```
 select 1 as tag, null as parent,
 '£'            as [a!1!b!xml],
 '&#163;'       as [a!1!c!xml],
 '&#163;'       as [a!1!d!element]
 for xml explicit
```